# How to validate if there is at least one checkbox selected out of 3 checkboxes in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

Ok so this is the code:

```
<input name="chkbx1" type="checkbox"
    ng-model="LoanReferData.Prop1"
    ng-class="Submitted?'ng-dirty':''" required>Prop 1</input>

<input name="chkbx2" type="checkbox"
    ng-model="LoanReferData.Prop2" ng-class="Submitted?'ng-dirty':''"
    required>Prop 2</input>

<input name="chkbx3" type="checkbox" ng-model="LoanReferData.Prop3"
    ng-class="Submitted?'ng-dirty':''" required>Other</input>


<span class="error" ng-show="((frmLoanRefer.chkbx1.$dirty || Submitted) && frmLoanRefer.chkbx1.$error.required) || 
                                                            ((frmLoanRefer.chkbx2.$dirty || Submitted) && frmLoanRefer.chkbx2.$error.required) || 
                                                            ((frmLoanRefer.chkbx3.$dirty || Submitted) && frmLoanRefer.chkbx3.$error.required)  ">
                            * please select atleast 1 property is required.</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an 'ng-true-value' attribute in your inputs as example

```
<input name="chkbx1" type="checkbox" ng-true-value="true"
                            ng-model="LoanReferData.Prop1"
                            ng-class="Submitted?'ng-dirty':''" required>Prop 1</input>

<input name="chkbx2" type="checkbox" ng-true-value="true"
                            ng-model="LoanReferData.Prop2" ng-class="Submitted?'ng-dirty':''"
                            required>Prop 2</input>

<input name="chkbx3" type="checkbox" ng-model="LoanReferData.Prop3" ng-true-value="true"
                            ng-class="Submitted?'ng-dirty':''" required>Other</input>

{{LoanReferData}}
```

And here is an answer

```
{"Prop1":"true","Prop2":"true","Prop3":false}
```

Comment: now that i have those values . how can i count all the 'TRUE' > 0 ?

Comment: you can do this in your controller by angularForeach as example

Answer (score 0):

you can try with !frmLoanRefer.LoanReferData.Prop1 instead of frmLoanRefer.chkbx1.$dirty. The same for frmLoanRefer.chkbx2.$dirty and frmLoanRefer.chkbx3.$dirty